# How to connect database and login layout in Android?

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, authentication

I am newbie in creating android app. I have created a database using SQLite and a simple login layout using eclipse. Now I want to connect my login page and the database I created so that when the user enters his/her username and password it will then open the main menu of the application. I am hoping for someone who could help me on how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your implementation of [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)

Example see [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

Comment: Thank you! I have created an OpenHelper, but then I don't know what to do next in order for me to connect it into my login page.

Comment: from your activity instantiate your helper and query it for the login/password pair.